# What is the best way to store site configuration data?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, oop

I have a question about storing site configuration data.

We have a platform for web applications. The idea is that different clients can have their data hosted and displayed on their own site which sits on top of this platform. Each site has a configuration which determines which panels relevant to the client appear on which pages.

The system was originally designed to keep all the configuration data for each site in a database. When the site is loaded all the configuration data is loaded into a SiteConfiguration object, and the clients panels are generated based on the content of this object. This works, but I find it very difficult to work with to apply change requests or add new sites because there is so much data to sift through and it's difficult maintain a mental model of the site *and* its configuration.

Recently I've been tasked with developing a subset of some of the sites to be generated as PDF documents for printing. I decided to take a different approach to how I would define the configuration in that instead of storing configuration data in the database, I wrote XML files to contain the data. I find it much easier to work with because instead of reading meaningless rows of data which are related to other meaningless rows of data, I have meaningful documents with semantic, readable information with the relationships defined by visually understandable element nesting.

So now with these 2 approaches to storing site configuration data, I'd like to get the opinions of people more experienced in dealing with this issue on dealing with these two approaches. What is the best way of storing site configuration data? Is there a better way than the two ways I outlined here?

**note:** StackOverflow is telling me the question appears to be subjective and is likely to be closed. I'm not trying to be subjective. I'd like to know how best to approach this issue next time and if people with industry experience on this could provide some input.

Comment: fyi - Stack Overflow would be telling you the question appears to be subjective because it contains the word "best" in the title...  and you're asking for opinions, which is the definition of subjective imho

Comment: "The best way" is subjective by definition for a question where there are too many situation-specific and influential variables.

Comment: By configuration you mean content and site structure? There is nothing wrong with putting this data into tables. As long as you've got an (user) interface to do the tasks needed to maintain the (sub)sites. Using Management Studio isn't the way to do this.

Comment: @rdkleine, Yes, configuration site & structure. I've suggested doing a UI to the bosses but they shot the idea down (money), but I'll bring it up again!! @Graphain & @Jon, I guess then by definition it is subjective, but I'm not trying to start arguments!! :-)

Comment: Maintaining sites using SQL uses a lot more time then using UI. And time is money....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the information is needed for per client specific configuration it is probably best done in a database with an admin tool written for it so that non technical people can also manage it. Also it's easier that way when you need versioning/history on it. XML isn't always the best on that part. Also XML is harder to maintain in the end (for non technical people).

Do you read out the XML every time from disk (performance hit) or do you keep it cached in memory? Either solution you choose, caching makes a big difference in the end for performance.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: I am currently reading the xml each time from the disk, but it's easy to store the data in the cache if needed. This subset of the system only runs periodically so currently disk performance is not really an issue

Answer (score 0):

You're using ASP.NET so what's wrong with web.config for your basic settings (if it's per project deploy), then as you've said, custom XML or database configuration settings for anything more complicated (or if you have multiple users/clients with the same project deploy)?

I'd only use custom XML documents for something like a "site layout document" where things won't change that often and you're going to have lots of semi-meaningless data (e.g. 23553123). And layout should be handled by css as much as possible anyway.

Comment: each file is ~20kb so it's not really practical to store it in web.config. I see what you're saying though

Answer (score 0):

For our team XML is a good choice (app.config or web.config or custom configuration file, it depends), but sometimes it is better to design configuration API to make configurations in code. For example [modern IoC containers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) has in-code configuration APIs with [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). This approach can give benefits if you need to configure many similar to each other entities or want to achive good human readability. But this doesn't works if non-programmers need to make configurations.